# How can I use TypeScript code in an existing Node project?

Tags: node.js, typescript, puppeteer

I currently have a Node project which uses Puppeteer.

```
import puppeteer from "puppeteer-extra";
const browser = await puppeteer.launch(...);
```

I discovered [this project](https://github.com/dougwithseismic/npm-definitely-not-a-robot) which seems to try to extend it and wanted to try it out. However it is TypeScript code.

I read that one solution is to use `ts-import`. I modified my code:

```
import * as tsImport from 'ts-import'
const HumanBrowser = await tsImport.load('HumanBrowser.ts')
const browser = await HumanBrowser.launch(...);
```

It seems to load the TypeScript file, but can't find `puppeteer-extra` (which the TypeScript code is trying to import)

```
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'puppeteer-extra' imported from /.cache/ts-import/code/HumanBrowser.mjs
    at packageResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:853:9)
    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:910:20)
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1130:11)
    at ModuleLoader.defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:396:12)
    at ModuleLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:365:25)
    at ModuleLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:240:38)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:85:39)
    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:84:36) {
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
```

`ts-import` says it is for importing TypeScript to JavaScript. I guess JavaScript is different from Node.js.  Is there something where I can similarly import into Node?

I've also read that TypeScript code can be "built" first then used. I ran `npm run build` as there is a `project.json` and it created some files. But it was not clear to me how I then import those into my Node project.

It is not a lot of code, would it be easier to just try to rewrite it in Node? The syntax seems similar.

Comment: _"I guess JavaScript is different from Node.js"_ - Node is a runtime **for JavaScript**.

Comment: Does this mean that typescript code cannot work with node?

Comment: TypeScript compiles to JS.

Comment: Don't use ts-import, don't try to convert the typescript code to javascript manually. Best option here is convert your project to TypeScript. You don't need to rewrite your code, your code can stay as JavaScript, you just need the build step for the package you are trying to use. The JavaScript/node entry point will be the one in the build folder. You'll need a typescript file to interface with the library

Comment: This library looks poorly maintained, basically a pet project. I wasn't able to get it to work. I'd just avoid it. Why do you need to use it in the first place? What original problem are you trying to solve with it? This seems like an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676) since there may be a better, more typical solution that doesn't require resorting to a random package with 6 stars. If you're being blocked by some site, please ask about that original problem--which site, and what are you trying to do on that site?

Comment: What the package is trying to do is exactly what I wanted to try to implement in my project so it sounded ideal.  Trying to get it to work seemed to make it become an XY problem.  Anyways, the original author just chimed in saying he'll look at it next week so I'll wait and give him a chance then move on

Comment: But the question is: why do you want to implement things like mouse wiggle in your project? I've never seen a need for this having scraped hundreds/thousands of sites. If you can show a site that is blocking you, there may well be a very straightforward way to avoid the block. Even if the author gets back to you, it's probably not necessary to do mouse wiggling and so forth in order to avoid a block.